# Have two different versions of arrow operator?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, operator-overloading

I have the following class for locking objects:

```
#include <memory>

template <class Type, class Mutex>
class LockableObject {
 public:
  class UnlockedObject {
   public:
    UnlockedObject(Mutex &mutex, Type &object)
        : mutex_(mutex), object_(object) {}
    UnlockedObject(UnlockedObject &&other) = default;

    // No copying allowed
    UnlockedObject(const UnlockedObject &) = delete;
    UnlockedObject &operator=(const UnlockedObject &) = delete;

    ~UnlockedObject() { mutex_.unlock(); }

    Type *operator->() { return &object_; }   // Version 1
    // Type &operator->() { return object_; } // Version 2


   private:
    Mutex &mutex_;
    Type &object_;
  };

  template <typename... Args>
  LockableObject(Args &&... args) : object_(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

  UnlockedObject Lock() {
    mutex_.lock();
    return UnlockedObject(mutex_, object_);
  }

 private:
  Mutex mutex_;
  Type object_;
};
```

I would like to use it as follows to lock and unlock access to a shared object. The second example makes use of the `->` operators's ability to apply itself multiple times:

```
  // Example 1
  {
    LockableObject<std::string, std::mutex> locked_string;
    auto unlocked_string = locked_string.Lock();
    // This is what I want:
    unlocked_string->size(); // works for version 1, breaks for version 2
  }

  // Example 2
  {
    LockableObject<std::unique_ptr<std::string>, std::mutex> locked_string(std::unique_ptr<std::string>(new std::string()));
    auto unlocked_string = locked_string.Lock();
    // This is what I want:
    unlocked_string->size(); // works for version 2, breaks for Version 1

    // Workaround
    unlocked_string->get()->size(); // works for version 1, but is not nice
  }
```

**Can the class somehow be changed to have both examples use `unlocked_string->size()` instead of the workaround with `->get()`? Possibly by using template specialisation or something similar?**

Comment: Consider `LockablePtr` type?

Comment: Overload `operator()` to get something like `unlocked_string()->size()`. The problem really is that your `get()` is coming from the `std::unique_ptr`. If you would like to get rid of `get()` you will have to specialize the template for `unique_pointer`

Comment: @subzero specializing for `unique_ptr`, or even better, have version 2 for `Type`s with an overloaded `operator->` and version 1 for the other `Type`s would be fine... any more details on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the hints and answers. I ended up using the following to detect presence of the arrow operator:

```
template <class> struct type_sink { typedef void type; };  // consumes a type, and makes it `void`
template <class T> using type_sink_t = typename type_sink<T>::type;
template <class T, class = void> struct has_arrow : std::false_type {};
template <class T> struct has_arrow<T, type_sink_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().operator->())> > : std::true_type {};
```

And then conditionally enabling or disabling the two versions of the functions like this:

```
template <class CopyType = Type>
typename std::enable_if<!has_arrow<CopyType>::value, CopyType *>::type
operator->() { return &object_; }  // Version 1

template <class CopyType = Type>
typename std::enable_if<has_arrow<CopyType>::value, CopyType &>::type
operator->() { return object_; }  // Version 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Write `LockablePtr` and `LockableValue` types.

Have `LockableObject` conditionally pick which one of the above to be based on the type passed in.  Detect smart pointers using some kind of SFINAE or traits or somesuch.

This choice can be via a `using` alias, or via inheritance with `using` to get parent constructors.

```
namespace details {
  template<template<class...>class, class, class...>
  struct can_apply : std::false_type {};
  template<class...>struct voider{using type=void;};
  template<class...Ts>using void_t=typename voider<Ts...>::type;
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply<Z, void_t<Z<Ts...>>, Ts...> : std::true_type {};
}
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
using can_apply = details::can_apply<Z, void, Ts...>;

template<class T>
using star_r = decltype( *std::declval<T>() );
template<class T>
using is_ptr_like = can_apply< star_r, T >;
```

`is_ptr_like` is a trait for things you can unary dereference.

Imagine you have both `LockablePtr<T,M>` and `LockableValue<T,M>` written.

```
template<class T, class M>
using Lockable = 
  typename std::conditional< is_ptr_like<T&>::value,
    LockablePtr<T, M>,
    LockableValue<T, M>
  >::type;

template<class T, class M>
struct LockableObject:Lockable<T,M> {
  using Lockable<T,M>::Lockable;
};
```

and done.

As an aside, your choice to store

```
Type&
```

seems like a bad one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer and help pointing me in the right direction! In the end, I ended up doing something very similar. Could you elaborate though why you think storing Type& is a bad idea? I need it to access object_ through the UnlockedObject class...

Comment: @jan On second read it is ok; I thought it was in the lockable object not the unlocked object.